# What is the replacement of Graphics and Pen class in uwp app?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, uwp

This is a WinForm code

```
 private EasyScript eScript;
    /// <summary>
    /// Graphics object we'll draw on to in order to produce a signature
    /// image.
    /// </summary>
    private Graphics graphics;
    /// <summary>
    /// Raster backing the graphics object.
    /// </summary>
    private Bitmap raster;
    /// <summary>
    /// Pen we'll use to create strokes on our graphics object.
    /// </summary>
    private Pen pen;
    /// <summary>
    /// The last point we captured.
    /// </summary>
    private Coordinate lastPoint = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not the next event we receive should clear the signature.
    /// </summary>
    private bool clearOnNext = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// The current stroke count.
    /// </summary>
    private int strokeCount = 0;
    /// <summary>
    /// The amount to scale the coordinates by.
    /// </summary>
    private double scaleFactor = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ExampleForm"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ExampleForm()
    {
        //Create a new EasyScript object.
        this.eScript = new EasyScript();

        //Register ourselves as a signature listener.
        eScript.AddListener(this);

        //Initialize our form.
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Initialize our drawing components.
        raster = new Bitmap(signaturePictureBox.Width, signaturePictureBox.Height);
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(raster);

        //Enable high quality drawing.
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

        //Calculate our scale factor based on the size of the picture box.
        scaleFactor = signaturePictureBox.Width / eScript.GetSignatureProtocol().GetWidth();

        //Clear the picture box.
        ClearSignatureBox();

        // this allows the form to preview all keyboard events before other parts of the form are allowed
        // to get them. If a particular keyboard event is from a ScripTouch device, 
        // we can prevent the event from propogating to other form elements, such as a TextBox.
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.cardSwipeInfoTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
        this.signatureInfoTextBox.ReadOnly = true;
    }
```

I need to convert this in my UWP app. However i can use WriteableBitmap in place of Bitmap and SolidColorBrush in place of Pen. But what should be for Graphics class.

Anyhow everything is solved if i consider graphics as a WriteableBitmap apart from these below lines

`graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality; graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;`

and 
`graphics.FillRectangle(Colors.White, 0, 0, signature.Width, signature.Height);`

and 
`graphics.DrawLine(pen, (float)(lastPoint.X * scaleFactor), (float)(lastPoint.Y * scaleFactor), (float)(coordinate.X * scaleFactor), (float)(coordinate.Y * scaleFactor));`

signature is my image object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: graphics is [WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap)

Answer (score 3):

The [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class under `System.Drawing` namespace is more like [`CanvasDrawingSession`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession.htm) class of [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D). Win2D is an easy-to-use Windows Runtime API for immediate mode 2D graphics rendering with GPU acceleration which is available for UWP app.

For example, for `graphics.InterpolationMode` property you may try [`CanvasImageInterpolation`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasImageInterpolation.htm) instead. The [`Antialiasing`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/P_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_Antialiasing.htm) property of `CanvasDrawingSession`  defined similar features as `SmoothingMode` has.   `CanvasDrawingSession` also has [`FillRectangle`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_FillRectangle_3.htm) and [`Drawline`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_DrawLine_3.htm) methods as you showed above from `Graphics`.

So you can try to use Win2D library in UWP app to implement the same features. For more details about how to use Win2D please reference the `README.md` of the [official site](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) and for samples please reference the [official samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/tree/master/samples).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WritableBitmapEx library
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WriteableBitmapEx

You can add this package to your project using nuget.

With WritableBitmapEx, it is really easy to Draw polygons, shapes, lines etc, directly on images.

E.g.
bmp.DrawRectangle(cornerPoints[0].X, cornerPoints[0].Y, cornerPoints[2].X, cornerPoints[2].Y, Colors.Red);

You can find tons of drawing examples with WritableBitmapEx on github
https://github.com/reneschulte/WriteableBitmapEx