# Need help converting custom C# Windows forms controls to custom C# Universal Windows Platform controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uwp

I am converting a C# windows forms app to a C# universal windows platform (UWP) app. In this app, there are custom controls that use the Paint event to add a handler method.  In this handler you get a PaintEventArgs object, and from there a Graphic object where drawing can be done. I need to do the same in UWP, but I haven’t found I way to get a Graphic object in UWP.

For what I have seen, you can only create custom controls in UWP by composing other controls that the platform provides and by setting their parameters. But this is not enough for my app.  I need a Graphics object to do precise drawing.  Is there a way of getting this Graphics object in UWP?.  I know that with the MSIX package tool you can create an installer for the Windows Store  from a Windows Forms app, but I would like my app to be directly in UWP.

Also, I know that in Android, even if it is also XAML based, it is possible to extend the View class in java and override the OnDraw method.  Is  there something equivalent in Window UWP?

Using Visual Studio, an example of the C# windos form code is:

```
partial class MyCustomButton
{
    ...

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {           
        ...
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.MyCustomButton_Paint);
    }

 }

public partial class MyCustomButton : Button
{
    public MyCustomButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyCustomButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        ...

        /// Drawing on g

    }

}
```

Can something similar be done in UWL, even if it is XAML based?  Can a Graphics object be obtained? (I know that in Android I is possible).

---

Because of the comments received, I am going to add information and try to be more specific. The C# Windows.Form app that we want to  update is a tool for drawing and editing  diagrams of particular engineering processes. It calculates points and draws lines in subclasses of the UserControl class, in particular in the handlers of the Paint event. I would like to reuse all these calculations and code when I update to UWP, but it seems to me that it can only be done if a Graphic object is available to drawn on.  That’s why I would like to know if this Graphic object can be obtained in UWP, and if it can’t I would like some guidance  on how to reuse all that drawing code that is already there in the C# Windows.Form version of the app. Thx for all replies.

Comment: It probably **is** possible. However: do you really want to go that route? Relying on the graphic-container is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: It is better to tell us what end result you are looking for. Chances are 90% that WPF/UWP has something orders of magnitude better for it. | Also I think I should bote that .NET Core 3.0 will be released with WindowsForms support. To transfer framework projects over to Core 3.0 there is a conversion tool.

Comment: Google "xaml create custom button" to get ahead.

Comment: Yes, this is possible in XAML. Do you have a specific question? What have you tried so far? Usually it is far more easier to create custom controls in XAML without doing custom drawing.

Comment: Please read the edit that I have added to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graphics class from System.Drawing namespace is similar with CanvasDrawingSession class of Win2D. Win2D is available for UWP app by adding the Win2D NuGet package to your project.

There is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254561/what-is-the-replacement-of-graphics-and-pen-class-in-uwp-app), you can refer to it. And I followed the code example of this [official site](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) to add graphics, it worked well. So you could try to use use Win2D library to implement the same features.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thx.